# My rails5 app was deployed successfully, but breaks when I navigate to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Here are my Heroku logs after I pushed it to Heroku. I configured the database with "pg" and use "Sqlite3" for development. I must have done something wrong when I deployed it, can anyone help me please?

```
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.

###### WARNING:
       Removing `vendor/bundle`.
       Checking in `vendor/bundle` is not supported. Please remove this directory
       and add it to your .gitignore. To vendor your gems with Bundler, use
       `bundle pack` instead.
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
###### WARNING:
       No Procfile detected, using the default web server.
       We recommend explicitly declaring how to boot your server process via a Procfile.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.2
###### WARNING:
       You have the `.bundle/config` file checked into your repository
       It contains local state like the location of the installed bundle
       as well as configured git local gems, and other settings that should
       not be shared between multiple checkouts of a single repo. Please
       remove the `.bundle/` folder from your repo and add it to your `.gitignore` file.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-configuration
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
```

Here is my controller, I'm not sure if made a syntax error here. Can someone take a look at the controller and offer a hint.

```
 class CustomersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_customer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


      def home
      end

      # GET /customers
      # GET /customers.json
      def index
        if params[:refund].blank?
          @customers = Customer.all
        else
          @refund_id = Refund.find_by(status: params[:refund]).id
          @customers = Customer.where(:refund_id => @refund_id).order("created_at DESC")
        end
      end

      # GET /customers/1
      # GET /customers/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /customers/new
      def new
        @customer = current_user.customers.build
        @refund = Refund.all.map{ |c| [c.status, c.id]}
      end

      # GET /customers/1/edit
      def edit
        @refunds = Refund.all.map{ |c| [c.status, c.id]}
      end

      # POST /customers
      # POST /customers.json
      def create
        respond_to do |format|
          @refund = Refund.all.map{ |c| [c.status, c.id]}
          @customer = current_user.customers.build(customer_params)
          @customer.refund_id = params[:refund_id]

          if @customer.save
            format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: "You have successfully added a refund for #{@customer.last_name}." }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /customers/1
      # PATCH/PUT /customers/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @customer.update(customer_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: "You have successfully updated #{@customer.last_name}\'s refund."}
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @customer }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /customers/1
      # DELETE /customers/1.json
      def destroy
        @customer.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to customers_url, notice: "You have successfully deleted #{@customer.last_name}\'s refund." }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end



      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_customer
          @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def customer_params
          params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :amount, :note, :refund_id)
        end
    end
```

Here is my route.rb file
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get 'customers/home'
  resources :customers
  devise_for :users
  root 'customers#index'
 end

Comment: is there an error in there somewhere, can you provide a link to the site, also did you run the migrations to set up the database?

Comment: I did run the migration by running ' heroku run rails db:migrate' and it is still break down when i visit another page. Here is the link https://a1plusfinancial.herokuapp.com/

Comment: login page works, looks like it is something with your customers controller, Can you post the output of $ rake routes and the code for your customers controller?

Comment: Here the routes for the project:

Comment: Hey, Rice. I've added the controller, can you take a look at it and tell me what I did wrong. Thank you.

Comment: you still have not posted the routes, post the output or `$rake routes` or post your routes.rb file

Comment: Here is my route.rb file:                                                                                          Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get 'customers/home'
  resources :customers
  devise_for :users
  root 'customers#index'
 end

Comment: please delete that and post it in the question, I cant read that

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using windows, for the deploy into Heroku you have to follow

your Gemfile.lock file likely contains

```
PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86-mingw32
```

You need to remove

```
  x86-mingw32
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile